# Binding to a Dictionary with an ObjectDataSource

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, webforms

Is it possible to perform a 2 way databinding using an ObjectDataSource that returns a Dictionary as it's Data Object?

It works on the read side with the following syntax for the binding

```
<%# Bind("[field1]") %>
```

However when it comes time to update the dictionary I get the following error:

> Could not find a property named '[field1]' on the type specified by the DataObjectTypeName property in ObjectDataSource 'ObjectDataSource1'